# Broken links on the 10K tools page

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools

The [Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=links&daterange=last2days) page has broken links.

e.g.:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-user-posts
- https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions
- https://stackoverflow.com/tools/views-hot

Comment: This applies to sites across the Stack Exchange Network - reproduced on WebApps.SE

Comment: On english.SE, I cannot see http://english.stackexchange.com/tools/edits-hot, and http://english.stackexchange.com/tools/votes-hot too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, the new list will look like:

- [posts flagged as offensive or spam](/tools/flagged)
- [recently deleted posts](/tools?tab=delete)
- [recently closed questions](/tools?tab=close)
- [recently imported questions](/tools?tab=stats)
- [new answers to old questions](/tools/new-answers-old-questions)
- [suggested edit stats](/tools/suggested-edits)

The other routes were not used (we're talking < 10 times in 3 days *on the entire network*) and were also *crazy* expensive to render.  Seeing as we've moved and consolidated (and added to!) these lists on the other tabs, the old pages were legacy.  The other non-removed links for the routes that are commonly used will now point to the new tools tabs that have that content.

Comment: Not that I will die without "new-answers-old-questions", but I am sure your stats are wrong unless you mean < 10 users, as I personally hit it more than 10 times in the last 3 days on SO alone (easily 10 times a day for the last 3 days).  It's the tool I used the most (many times a day) to check for things to upvote, spam, and updated tools/technologies.  I can switch to "late answers", but I will be sad about the < 10 rep filter as it's now probably just a list to check for spam and thank you posts.

Comment: I have been using "new posts from new users" to find non-answers. I can usually find several posts to flag any time I bring that list up. The review tabs don't really do the trick for this, in my opinion. If we could get a tab showing answers from new users, this would help find a lot of trash.

Comment: I used to use new-answers-old-questions to look for recently posted spam, non-answers, and posts with broken formatting/... that needed editing.

Comment: @sth - This very moment I'm added new-answers-to-old-questions back in a faster loading way, I'll update this as soon as it's done.

Comment: @Philip - I just added that route in particular back, completely rewritten and *way* faster/lighter than before - appreciate the feedback on things you guys find useful.

Comment: @Jon's - We won't be adding this back, since that overlaps with `/review` functionality, you can find actually a few different breakdowns for new users here that give much more info: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers

Comment: @Nick - that is awesome, it's nearly my SO home page

Comment: @Nick - I don't see a good option for finding follow up "answers" (first answers and late answers don't really do it). Maybe an option to see self answers would do this (I think I requested that the other day, actually).

Comment: @sth - Starting in the next build we'll link the review as a tab on the tools page, which has this view breakdown in it.  While we won't remove the route I spoke of above for some time, start using `/review` (and suggesting improvements here if needed) as we'll *eventually* clean up that old view.

Comment: @Jon's - Also, see above comment :)