# Restore the 10k ability to see all closed/deleted posts in a list

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, recently-deleted, recently-closed

A bunch of 10k links were [removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89942/broken-links-on-the-10k-tools-page) early this month because:

> The other routes were not used (we're talking < 10 times in 3 days *on the entire network*) and were also *crazy* expensive to render.  Seeing as we've moved and consolidated (and added to!) these lists on the other tabs, the old pages were legacy.  The other non-removed links for the routes that are commonly used will now point to the new tools tabs that have that content.

I [defended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90068/so-no-one-cares-about-missing-features-on-10k-tools/90071#90071) most of that, but there is something I miss about the lists that isn't captured in the improved 10k tools: they contained every post in their category. Recently closed posts had every post that had ever been closed on the site if you burrowed far enough, not just the last ~50 in 30 days (on SO it's more like the last 50 in 3 hours). Same with recently deleted posts; it was over 30000 pages when I last looked at it.

I don't know of any easy way to get at that data anymore. Uses I've actually wanted in the few weeks since they were removed include:

- Seeing how often SO migrates posts to individual sites. Mods have access to this, but I don't want to bother them asking for data
- How many posts have been closed by a mod versus by vote
- How many posts were deleted by the OP versus by vote

I'd like some way to determine that information again. The simplest way seems to be to bring these particular lists back, or change the existing close/delete tabs so there's some way to get the complete history again. Recently imported posts falls into the same group -- I haven't actually missed that one yet, but it's another list that used to show the complete history that's now limited to just the recent posts

Comment: is this still wanted/needed? I'm not 100% clear what the purpose is here, like what problems are being solved.

Answer (score 28):

I agree completely.

The other day I had to go searching for a question that I suspected had been deleted by the OP to see what happened, but I realized that nothing in the Tools shows self-deleted posts anymore.

I think putting this information into the deleted posts tab would clutter things up too much. We don't really need to see this information very often (at least I don't), so I would prefer that the full list be brought back, even if it's just for the last 1/2/7/14/30 days.

I understand the old page [was expensive to render](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89942/broken-links-on-the-10k-tools-page/89944#89944), but if it's used infrequently as suggested, that means it can still provide information not available elsewhere at a low *overall* cost.

Comment: I constructed a test query on one of the local databases I have and I don't see how it's *that* expensive on the data side. Yeah it's not blazing fast, but it certainly isn't egregious.