# Better oversight for self-deleted answered questions

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, deleted-questions, self-delete

[Askers can delete their own question if it has no answer, or if it has a single answer with no upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented). The first case is generally fine: deleting an unanswered question rarely causes collateral damage. It can happen that someone was in the process of writing an answer, but if they feel that their answer-to-be is valuable enough, they can re-ask the question and answer it themselves. Deleting an answered question is more problematic. Common cases include:

- The answer says “it was a typo” or “you misread the directions” or something similar which won't ever help anyone else. In this case, deleting the thread is the right thing.
- The asker is new to Stack Exchange and thinks that solved questions should be deleted. We shouldn't let that happen.
- The asker wants to hide their tracks: they don't want their professor/boss/… to find out that they got help from Stack Exchange, and they delete their question as soon as they get an answer.

Deletion of an answered question by the asker happens with very little opportunity for review.

- The answerer won't notice anything unless they bookmarked the question and check back on it later, or they go and check the unemphasized section of their profile that lists their recently deleted posts.
- Users with the “moderator tools” privilege can check [recent deletions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete) but that list [omits self-deletions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92979/restore-the-10k-ability-to-see-all-closed-deleted-posts-in-a-list/93037#93037) ([thanks Behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244839/better-oversight-for-self-deleted-answered-questions#comment800444_244839)). Even if they were included, they'd be lost in the noise.
- Moderators have access to a [list of self-deleted posts](https://cs.stackexchange.com/admin/recently-self-deleted). It's yet another tool for mods to check and contains a lot of things that don't need review (unanswered questions, answers that turned out to be wrong or duplicates), so I'd like something better.

I'd like to have better oversight on answers indirectly deleted by the asker: prevent or at least flag the bad cases, without requiring too much busywork in the good cases.

I propose to **raise an automatic flag when a user deletes their question after it has been answered**. This seems fine to me as a moderator on a small site, but I have no idea whether that means 1 or 100 extra flags per day on SO.

An alternative solution would be to remove the ability to single-handedly delete answered questions altogether. The right solution depends on how many self-deleted answered questions fall into each category, which I don't have statistics for.

Comment: I like the flag option. But I feel that for sites like [so] this would make the flag queue shoot fireworks.

Comment: Maybe a timed mechanism in which if an answer doesn't gather any upvotes for a certain amount of  time it is assumed boring and doesn't prevent deletion, but before then it's just awaiting  votes?

Comment: Don't forget that as soon as an answer gets an upvote the question can't be self deleted. So if the answer has merit then this situation can't occur.

Comment: @JanDvorak Exactly the "I cheated and cover my tracks" questions tend to accumlate no votes; nobody likes homework dumps. (At least on [cs.SE].)

Comment: @ChrisF On small sites, the asker may be faster than readers. Especially in problematic cases. Maybe a cooldown is the answer: every answer adds 24 hours to a "deletion lock" during which the asker can not delete the new answer (i.e. not the question). If there are no upvotes after that, go for it.

Comment: I think that simply disallowing deletion if a zero score answer is present would be enough to avoid most of the misuse, and I don't think it would prevent all that many valid self-deletions. I've proposed [this and similar ideas in the past](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155933/preventing-misuse-of-question-self-deletion).

Comment: @Raphael - good point & I like your suggestion of a cool down period.

Comment: Users with 10K tools cannot see self-deletions: they are [excluded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93037/) from the list of recently deleted posts.

Comment: Another case (my own experience): I asked quite an [unpopular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072508/in-the-playground-how-to-turn-off-debug-mode). Then I (of course!) started a bounty on it. One has prepared a good answer and answered the question. I awarded the bounty and? was able to delete the question. Either it shouldn't be allowed or should be tracked (I decided to undelete my question some time later). Btw, maybe I should create a feature-request about not allowing to delete questions with bountied answers?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, 11504 questions with answers were deleted by their authors during the past 90 days. Therefore, this would generate on average ~128 flags per day. Excluding Stack Overflow and meta sites, 2200 questions with answers were deleted by their authors network-wide during the past 90 days.

Comment: I don't like the idea of moderators having to judge what's worth keeping and what not, possibly in areas way out of their expertise. It would be better to give answerers better tools for tracking the fate of their answers deleted in this particular way. An inbox notification, perhaps?

Comment: @Behaviour But that's what we (and other reviewers) do every day.

Comment: @Raphael The proposal here is for moderators to make the decisions, not reviewers. Moderators apply their delete-hammer in *kill it with fire* cases. Judging whether someone's attempt to answer a technical question resulted in something that justifies overriding self-deletion of the question is something rather different.

Comment: @Behaviour Again, that's something we moderators do regularly. On smaller (i.e. almost all) sites, that is: we don't have such a large reviewer crowd and have to get our hands dirty more frequently.

Comment: @MadScientist: No problem, I'll just downvote the answer before I delete my question!

Comment: @Raphael Also, on smaller (i.e., almost all) sites an answer to a boring question is quite likely not to pick up votes so is vulnerable to deletion for quite a long time. This can definitely be a problem: on [cs.se] at the moment, we're having a couple of homework questions turn up repeatedly, almost word-for-word duplicates. If zero-score answers get deleted with the questions, people spend time again and again answering the same question.

Comment: @Shog9 So what alternative methods of oversight can you offer? People posting homework questions and deleting as soon as they've had an answer is a recurring problem on [cs.se].

Comment: Honestly... The fix for this is probably something that'd discourage folks from answering questions where the author hasn't indicated some investment in the site (even if that's just... reading the "how to ask" page). @Gilles. Like the old "accept rate" indicator, except some sort of "I'm not a drive-by leech" indicator.

Comment: @Shog9 Or like the "min rep" filter that SO had for a brief moment of new nav testing.

Comment: 2018, this spring has seen an apparent uptick in the self-deleted questions after answer. I suspect this is more homework/delete to prevent it from being later found. The minimum rep for self-delete does have merit. If it takes 100 rep to comment, then it should take 100 rep to immediately self-delete. (a self-delete with rep less-than 100 should set a moderator review flag to determine if it is just a crappy question that needs deleting, or if it is a good question/answer that is attempted to be hidden).

Comment: @Shog9 - I think that there's already some discouraged answerers, with uninvested askers. Very often people show up with rep 1, or 101, and ask a question without so much as an upvote for a fair answer, probably not a revisit to find a better answer, and certainly not a checkmark to choose what they deem a correct answer. In all fairness they could have gone off to war or been hit by a bus; so **we** don't want to be the ones whom are rude - thus the 'one pointers' get ignored and a lot of unanswered questions drift off into the bit bin. There's an investment to comment, why not one to ask?

Comment: @ChrisF - Here's one example of the problem: The rep 1 user is low rep across the sites and asks on Meta for a site recommendation. They get a couple of downvotes and [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327937/where-to-ask-a-question-about-video-types/327948#327948), so they delete their question before the answer gets an upvote - and an answer that would help people in the future is lost.