# Please update privileges page for 10k rep - Access to Moderator Tools

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, privileges-page

The 10k tools page was [recently updated with removal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89942/broken-links-on-the-10k-tools-page) of routes that were not in active use.

However, the [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) for this has not been updated and still reflects the old routes:

> What's in the moderator tools?
>
> - posts flagged as offensive or spam
> - recently deleted posts
> - recently closed questions
> - see all recent edits in chronological order
> - new posts by new users
> - questions with newly created tags
> - new answers to old questions
> - recent questions with most view velocity
> - recent questions with most edit velocity
> - recent questions with most vote velocity

while it should be:

> What's in the moderator tools?
>
> - posts flagged as offensive or spam
> - recently deleted posts
> - recently closed questions
> - recently imported questions
> - new answers to old questions
> - suggested edit stats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a wiki, as are all of the priv wikis on this site.

Just perform whichever editing you think makes sense and we can pull in the updated versions.

Comment: I'm a diamond on SU and I don't see an edit link, what's up with that?

Comment: @Sathya [works fine for me](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-wiki/17). I'm also an SU mod (and not a meta.SO mod).

Comment: @nhinkle - I forgot that [tag wikis can be pushed only from Meta.SO](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2362/unable-to-propose-tag-wiki/2369#2369)