# Put the "review" link back in its proper place next to "tools" in the top navigation bar

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, 10k-tools, review, navigation

It seems one of my suggestions in [Usability Improvements for the > 10k Moderation Tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100462/usability-improvements-for-the-10k-moderation-tools) had been implemented. One or two days ago, the "review" link disappeared from the Tools and appeared on the top navigation bar.

This was a *great* usability improvement, as most 10k+ users that I know check both "review" and "tools" on a frequent basis. The (almost hidden) link to "review" that we used to have within Tools seemed quite inefficient. This has all been described in Proposal 2a of my feature request.

Starting August 15th, to the surprise of many, **the "review" link disappeared again!**

[image: No review link! Only tools, blog, meta, and faq]

I therefore propose that the **"review" link should be put back into the top bar** again. It allows for quick and easy navigation between two completely different moderation tools with expressly different use cases. We should be *encouraging* people with 10k+ rep to click on this link and spend some time helping to clean up the site.

The top bar for 10k+ users should really look like this:

[image: review, tools, blog, meta, faq]

If you *really* think that 5 links in the toolbar is too many (even considering the generally massive size of screens nowadays), then you could hide the "faq" link instead. It isn't really needed by 10k+ users, and if they do need to access it, they can always do so through the link in the footer at the bottom of the page.

The current "stop-gap" approach with nested tabs is a truly horrible piece of UI, unlikely to be discovered or frequented by the users we should be aiming to attract with this feature. Something else needs to be done, and it might as well be something that makes this *more* conspicuous rather than less.

Comment: I see it here on Meta and on SO, but over at [android.se] where I am a mod, it's gone. (It was there yesterday and I was glad of it.)

Comment: `review` hasn't been displaced by `blog`, I don't see it on sites where I have 10k rep, even when there is no `blog`.

Comment: As a 0.8k user here, I see `review - chat - main - about - faq`.  Like Al, on Android I see `mod - tools - chat - meta - faq`.  No other sites with 10k rep for me to test ...

Comment: @Gilles I just thought it had to do with the blog, since the "new" message would take up some more space.

Comment: I don't see it on sites where I am a 10k user. If I directly write the  URL, then I am able to access the review page.

Comment: @slhck you kind of shot yourself in the foot here with this question, I am going to have to mark this status-completed, cause I re-added the faux-crummy review tab - nested tabs is horrible UI wise - and Jeff does not approve of adding "review" link .... this should have been phrased differently. In particular "It wouldn't bother me as much if the link were still to be found in the Tools, but obviously it's gone from there as well:" ... cause now I fixed that which means it is complete

Comment: If you're fixing this question, I won't bother to ask a new one. Unfortunately, this one is still too new for me to add a bounty. Oh well, I guess I'll wait for round 2 of rejection. :-)

Comment: @Cody I'm absolutely fine with your additions!

Comment: @Cody I am pretty happy with my solution, let me know what you think - see amended reply

Answer (score 13):

I just changed the way the "tools" link behaves:

Tools page now has 2 modes. Review and Tools.

[image: mode1]

[image: mode2]

---

There is a pretty significant usability improvement as well.

We now "remember" where you last were including the tab, time range and tag filter (for review)

This allows you to resume your last activity effectively without bulking up the header too much. The header will simply link to your last activity.

Comment: By the time you get 10k tools, you shouldn't need that faq link in the header any more

Comment: @random, the way Jeff reads this question is ... review link is missing from tools ... please re-add. **NOT** it would be better to have the review link in the header.

Comment: @random agree there, please do a separate request on that - faq is in the footer anyway if 10ks really need access to it

Comment: Okay, thank you for explaining. Well, seems we'll have to live with that!

Comment: @Cody ask for the review link on top for 10k users, get a few people to agree with you and we may be able to change Jeffs mind on it, slhck shot himself in foot the way the question was asked

Comment: Well I only asked *why* it was gone. I explicitly said I'd like it to be in the navigation bar again and filed it as a bug. Because this is what the [original proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100462/usability-improvements-for-the-10k-moderation-tools) was anyway. It's still at 36 votes and open. @Cody

Comment: I'm fine however changing the question to "Please put the review link back in", if you'd agree (thus taking out the [status-completed]).

Comment: @slhck Fine with me just make it crystal clear

Comment: @slhck status added

Comment: This was a great idea -- I like it. Is this officially going to stay?

Comment: @slhck ... yeah this is staying

Comment: Hmm, okay. This is acceptable. At least it fixes the glaring usability problems. I'm glad that there's someone on the team who is willing to listen and be flexible about things. Removed the downvote and added an upvote.

Comment: One minor gripe, probably not worth opening a new bug report. The dividing line between Tools and Review looks great on SO and Meta. But it's MIA on the SE 2.0 sites, at least in the Beta theme like [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tools). I think it's definitely needed to emphasize that those are actually links to two *separate* pages. Should be trivial to add, right?

Comment: @random: I disagree completely about 10k users not needing the faq link -- I often paste links to the FAQ with anchors and it is much easier to do so if the link is there.

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, that link depends on your rep level.

- 0-199 rep: (none)
- 200 - 9999 rep: link to `/review`
- 10000+ rep: link to `/tools` (which should contain /review functionality)

So the change was a regression, and I reverted it.

Comment: I never fully understood why `review` is *within* `tools` when it isn't there from the start. It even has its own URL which would hint at it being a different section altogether. Given that, for example, 10k users wouldn't need the FAQ link anymore, isn't there a chance to get it back in? (as @waffles and random said)

Comment: Some say regression, others say improvement. I use that link all the time, I'd like it to be easily available. One would think you'd like it too; it helps encourage people to spend time cleaning up the site. Nested tabs are not actual UI. If you don't want this in the toolbar, some other sensible location needs to be found.

Comment: @Jeff see the last comment on my post above