# Make the chat link one click away in the new top bar

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat, top-bar

In the new header could we please move the chat link back to where it was? (One click away)

As a daily frequent to the JavaScript room that's the one link I'd love to have visible 100% of the time.

Aside from that, I actually love the new header. (Maybe take it a step further an add a customizable header with (X) link spots for your most used links?)

Just my thoughts

Comment: Also very important to drive more people *to* the chat (an essential part of StackOverflow)

Comment: Here's a userscript I *Mircrowaved*  for you if you want it back now. https://gist.github.com/connor1995JS/7800696/raw/f04999bb0ecc7b5a9dca5f4eaf6c830621276368/restore-chat-link.user.js

Comment: Related: [StackExchange drop down hiding chat, blog and log out, concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209971/stackexchange-drop-down-hiding-chat-blog-and-log-out-concerns)

Comment: Why did Community bump this question?

Comment: @Emrakul Because it has no upvoted answers.

Comment: @Adam you can post official decline reason, hopefully it would save this question from the bump loop... :)

Comment: @Adam with 26 upvotes, I really think that those 26 users deserve some kind of explanation why it's declined. Will it clutter the design? Not technically possible? Other reason why it's bad idea?

Comment: I support the idea to make more engagement to participate in the chat, since it is featured as the 3rd place and users are directed there when they have unacceptable subjective questions. I think that making the chat so unaccessible makes it a dump (except perhaps for moderators), instead of a chat, and so becomes useless.

Comment: @Adam How about a link to chat in the sidebar?

Comment: @JohnLocke Maybe! I don’t know if we want to make chat *that* prominent, considering that we’re not putting much, if any, dev effort into it these days. But I’m also not strongly opposed personally. Not sure if there’s an existing feature request for this, but if not, mind writing one up?

Comment: @Adam I looked around and found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness/311456#311456) proposing a bunch of cool sidebar features (and might just win the award for most upvotes on the least popular OP). I also found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103077/include-both-the-chat-and-blog-links-permanently-in-the-header) which appears to be a duplicate of the question here.

Comment: @JohnLocke Cool, thanks. I’m not at a computer at the moment, but I think it’s a safe bet that this is on a list somewhere internally for consideration then.

Comment: @AdamLear You can use Stack Exchange with your mind??? :) I bet the HTML parsing takes forever.

Comment: Stop pinging me D:

Answer (score -3):

I have never used the chat link since the first time I have used it. After the first time, every single time I just do <kbd>C-t</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd><down></kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>.

**UPDATE**

Also, the chat link is still at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: Not exactly the best solution to the problem

Comment: The point was it was not a problem.

Comment: I think the big issue is fewer people will find the chat rooms in the first place.

Comment: Well, we could just [spam all the comments with links instead](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)