# Add a link in the top bar to the main blog

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, blog

The master blog (https://blog.stackoverflow.com) has a new shiny design, and is quite content rich now, and believe it deserves a *prominently* placed link.

The blog is the area where Stack Overflow as a company report news, business matters, and changes to the sites and how they are working on new things (etc). As such it matters to all users and so is an important aspect to the experience on all sites as a whole.

It would be good if more users read it, as they'd pick up more info and knowledge about the company and the site's workings - which can only be a good thing.

However, the link to this magical world full of unicornical info is way down the bottom masquerading as a typical *boring footer link*, like T&C and Privacy Policy links, etc.

The blog is worthy of more dignity than this!

As such, I believe the most suitable and natural place is a link on the black top bar. (Actually on the top bar, not in a drop down.)

Not sure of the exact place on the top bar, as I'm sure there'll be considerations I'm not aware of (responsive design requirements, future plans for top bar spaces etc).

Comment: Additionally, [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266747/amazing-all-sites-have-blogs) suggests there should be no "Blog" link in the drop down when the site being viewed has no blog of its own. So I suggest that actioning the other question *and* implementing this feature request will provide a better and more logical overall UI with regards to blogs. The blog link in the dropdown will only exist to link to the blog of the site currently being viewed (if it has one), and the top bar will link to the site's main blog always - regardless of where you are.

Comment: I think that the answer I provided [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103077/include-both-the-chat-and-blog-links-permanently-in-the-header) indicates that other than not being precisely on the top bar you almost have your wish on Meta SE already.

Comment: @PolyGeo I don't want chat at the top, this has been discussed as it woud make it too popular (too many people makes it less possible to help anyone etc). Also, the blog link in the drop down does go to the main blog on all sites. See the linked bug report in my top comment here - ie go to SuperUser and click the blog link and see what happens ;)

Comment: It could be worth moving that bug report link into your question to help save others thinking your post was less researched than it now obviously has been.

Comment: @PolyGeo I did initially, but removed it as I concluded the bug report is a separate issue really. It's *related* to my request in that both changes would work together, but it's not *relevant* :)

Answer (score 3):

I disagree that the Stack Overflow blog needs more prominence than it already [has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266698).  As well as being available from the pulldown at top left, whenever new blog posts are written they appear in the right hand sidebar.

While the workings of the Stack Overflow company may be of interest to those of us who frequent Meta SE and/or the site Metas, to make its blog more prominent can I think only distract from the prime mission of our sites which I think is to provide focussed Q&A at the local site level where communities are built.

I don't think the non-Meta users of our Main sites will want to lose screen real estate, and I think search only users of our site will not have the vested interest to follow a link to the blog even if it were prominent.

Comment: We do not already have what I am asking. I am *specifically* asking for a link to the main Stack Overflow blog *and* in the top bar, and the link in the dropdown does neither of those things. Because the blog link does not go to the main blog on sites which have their own blog. Besides, I want it in the top bar because I feel it's worthy and would be good to get other users reading the blog. Having it in the dropdown is not the same thing :) Additionally, going by Anna's comments in the bug report, the drop down blog link to the main blog may well disappear soon.

Comment: @James I did not make clear in two places that I was expressing my own opinion/reading of the situation - I have now addressed that via an edit to my answer.

Comment: It was no problem, I meant stats for this is impossible so it's just heresay - I.E. it can be nothing else :)

Comment: @PolyGeo Not anymore...